# How to assign a button to a displayed image in the gallery - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, gallery

I'm using [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-swipe-slider/) nice code for a simple slider:

http://codepen.io/GCW/pen/ByovxG

I added some navigation buttons, but I don't know how to call the selected images ID referred to the button ID.

```
<button id="firstbutt">First Gallery</button>
<button id="secondtbutt">Second Gallery</button>
<button id="thirdbutt">Third Gallery</button>
<button id="fourthbutt">Fourth Gallery</button>

<img id="image1" .../>
<img id="image2" .../>
<img id="image3" .../>
<img id="image4" .../>
```

I'm not so good with jQuery and the code has a lot of vars, but I think I should get the # position of the image I'd like to display. There seems to be an array stored for that.

```
slidePos = new Array(slides.length);
```

Comment: "selected images ID referred to the button ID" What do you want... Your Qn not clear?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, one solution would be to add a class to each button/image pair.

So it would look like this:

```
<button id="firstbutt" class="first">First Gallery</button>
<button id="secondtbutt" class="second">Second Gallery</button>
<button id="thirdbutt" class="third">Third Gallery</button>
<button id="fourthbutt" class="fourth">Fourth Gallery</button>

<img id="image1" class="first" .../>
<img id="image2" class="second".../>
<img id="image3" class="third".../>
<img id="image4" class="fourth".../>
```

Then you'd be able to hide/show the groups accordingly using jQuery:

```
$(".first").show();
```

This way, you have an association between the buttons and associated images.

Comment: show() is used to show or hide an element with the 'display' property. there are no hidden elements in the gallery

Comment: I was just using show() as an example of what could be done.  Didn't mean to suggest he HAD to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttons = $('button');
    var images = $('img');

    buttons.each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            images.each(function(){$(this).hide();});
            images.eq($(this).index()).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/me8sy4pw/